# Json Tree - Expression Evaluation

Tags: python, json, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a json represents mathematical expression in the below format and need to evaluate the same.

```
{
        "operator":"+",
        "params": ["60" , {
            "operator":"/",
            "params":[
                "alias3",
                {
                    "operator":"+",
                    "params":["alias1","alias2"]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
```

An example of the above structure would look like:

```
{
        "operator":"abs",
        "params": [
            {
                "operator":"/",
                "params":[
                    {
                        "operator": "*",
                        "params": 
                        [
                            "100",
                            {
                                "operator": "/",
                                "params": ["2000", "40"]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "operator":"+",
                        "params":[
                            "30",
                            {
                                "operator": "*",
                                "params": [
                                    "25",
                                    {
                                        "operator": "-",
                                        "params": ["60", "15"]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Note:

- Operators used are +, -, *, /, abs
- Every operator has exactly 2 params except abs()
- at any given level any of the above operators can be present.

above json is a representation of `abs((100*(2000/40))/(30+(25*(60-15))))` and it evaluates to 4.329

Please help me to evaluate this json expression tree.

Solution I found:
This problem is almost similar to the Evaluation of Expression tree. But, input is in json format. This is where I am struggling to read json data.
Psuedo code like below when input is in tree (using nodes) format - This would be a recursive function.

```
Let t be the syntax tree
If  t is not null then
      If t.info is operand then  
         Return  t.info
      Else
         A = solve(t.left)
         B = solve(t.right)
         return A operator B
         where operator is the info contained in t
```

I tried to use same psuedo code and read input from json.
But, I'm unable to find the correct root and leaf case to exit from recursive function.
By looking at json one thing can be noted that leaf case will be "string" and non-leaf will be "dictionary". But, problem is "operator" is also string and operator never be leaf. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `type` of the leaf to determine if you have to parse it a float or if it's a dict and therefore to use the recurtion.

You can use some `if` on `operator` to determine with operation to apply. (here I use operator package to avoid some ifs)

```
import operator
json_operations = {
        "operator":"abs",
        "params": [
            {
                "operator":"/",
                "params":[
                    {
                        "operator": "*",
                        "params":
                        [
                            "100",
                            {
                                "operator": "/",
                                "params": ["2000", "40"]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "operator":"+",
                        "params":[
                            "30",
                            {
                                "operator": "*",
                                "params": [
                                    "25",
                                    {
                                        "operator": "-",
                                        "params": ["60", "15"]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}

operators = {"+": operator.add,
             "-": operator.sub,
             "*": operator.mul,
             "/": operator.truediv
             }

def do_params(p):
    if type(p) is str:
        return float(p)
    else:
        return do_operations(p)

def do_operations(p):

    if "operator" in p:
        params_1 = do_params(p["params"][0])
        if len(p["params"]) > 1:
            params_2 = do_params(p["params"][1])

        if p["operator"] == "abs":
            return abs(params_1)
        else:
            return operators[p["operator"]](params_1, params_2)

    return 0
res = do_operations(json_operations)

output : 
4.329004329004329
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function, where `params` is mapped by the function itself. The base case is when the function's argument is not a dictionary (but a primitive type).

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

def solve(tree):
    if type(tree) is not dict:
        return float(tree)  # convert string to float
    return {
        "+": add,
        "-": sub,
        "*": mul,
        "/": truediv,
        "abs": abs
    }[tree["operator"]](*map(solve, tree["params"]))
```

The dictionary literal allows conversion of the operator name to the actual operator function, and the splash operator provides for dealing equally well with unary and binary operators, providing all the "solved" parameters (1 or 2) to the dynamically retrieved function.